# What is the meaning of "within-season variation"?

Tags: ecology, terminology, environment, climate-change, phenology

I am reading a paper about phenology and climate change for my assignment and I found this concept "within-season variation", can someone explain it to me? and how it is related to changes over time?

Comment: Could you link to the paper please

Answer (score 2):

"**Within-season variation**" may be referring to one of two things (depending on the context):

1. More commonly: **the variation of a variable within a given season (i.e., between months or days within that season)**.

   - [Öst (1999)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1370189?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) demonstrates an example of this use (in the context of *breeding* season).
2. Less commonly: the variation of a variable between the same season of different (often consecutive) years. Though this would more often be termed "**between years**". This is as opposed to "between seasons" which would be be between two different seasons of the same year.